# AWS SAM local example fails with image not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, sam

I'm trying to run the ASW sam local example with 'sam local invoke' but get this error:

```
Could not find amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-nodejs12.x:rapid-1.6.2 image locally and failed to pull it from docker
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This started working after I created a docker account and was logged in in Docker Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Switch your Docker from windows container to Linux container:

[image: Image showing how to switch between Linux/windows container in Windows 10]

Else try to pull the image manually you will get the actual error.
https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-java8